# Prime generating number finder not producing correct output

Tags: java, debugging, primes

I'm working on this problem:

> Consider the divisors of 30: 1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30.
> It can be seen that for every divisor d of 30, d+30/d is prime.
>
> Find the sum of all positive integers n not exceeding 100 000 000
> such that for every divisor d of n, d+n/d is prime.

and I thought for sure I had it, but alas, it's apparently giving me the wrong answer (`12094504411074`).

I am fairly sure my sieve of Eratosthenes is working (but maybe not), so I think the problem is somewhere in my algorithm. It seems to get the right answer for `n = 30` (`1+2+6+10+22+30 = 71` - is this correct?), but as numbers get larger, it apparently stops working.

Here is my Java code:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
public class Generators {
static HashSet<Integer> hSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int n = 100000000; 
    sieveErat(n + 1); //Fill a hashSet with prime numbers
    System.out.println("Sieve complete");
    int check = 0; 
    
    long sum = 3;
    
    
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
        int numDivisors = 0; 
        int numPrimeChecks = 0; 
        boolean done = false;
        if(!hSet.contains(i+1)){ //i+1 must be a prime number for i to be prime generating
            continue;
        }
        else{
            for(int j = 2; j < i/2; j++){
                if(i%j == 0){
                    numDivisors++;
                check = j + i/j;
                if(hSet.contains(check)){
                    done = true;
                    numPrimeChecks++;
                }
            }else{
                break;
            }           
        
    }
            if(numPrimeChecks == numDivisors && done){
                
                sum += i; 
            }
        }
    
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}

public static void sieveErat(int N){
boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[N + 1];
    
    for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
        isPrime[i] = true;
        //count++;
    }
    // mark non-primes <= N using Sieve of Eratosthenes
    
    for (int i = 2; i*i <= N; i++) {

        // if i is prime, then mark multiples of i as nonprime
        // suffices to consider mutiples i, i+1, ..., N/i
        if (isPrime[i]) {
            for (int j = i; i*j <= N; j++) {
                isPrime[i*j] = false;
            //    count--;
            }
        }
        
    }
   
   
    for(int i = 2; i < isPrime.length; i++){
        if(isPrime[i]){
            hSet.add(i);
        }
    }
   // System.out.println(count);

  
   
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maths of your sieve looks fine to me. I hacked it around to use a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) which is much more space efficient. Is `5761455` primes below 100,000,000 correct?

Once I got your code working I got the same figure you get (`12094504411075`) what figure **should** you be getting?

I think this bit is wrong (I have changed the variable names to match the question for clarity)

```
    for(int d = 2; d < Math.sqrt(n+3); d++) {
      if (n % d == 0) {
        numDivisors++;
        int check = d + n / d;
        if (primes.get(check)) {
          // **** What does done mean??? ****
          //done = true;
          numPrimeChecks++;
        } else {
          // **** Added! Got a divisor that did not check. No point in going on.
          break;
        }
      } else {
        // **** Why break here??? ****
        //break;
      }

    }
```

**NB** I have edited this code to reflect what we finally decided was a correct solution.

Why are you breaking out of the `d` loop as soon as you hit a `d` that does not divide `n`? Surely that cannot be right.

However, I think you **can** break out of the `d` loop when you have a divisor that does not check.

Also, what is your intended functionality of `done`? It seems to have no real function.

And, why do you start `sum` at `3`?

Removing the `break` I now get the value `1739023853139`. Is this correct?

**Added**

Here's my sieve. Identical to yours but builds a `BitSet` which is a much more efficient structure than a `HashSet` in this case:

```
public static BitSet sieveOfEratosthenes(int n) {
  BitSet isPrime = new BitSet(n);

  // Iniially all numbers are prime.
  for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    isPrime.set(i);
  }

  // mark non-primes <= N using Sieve of Eratosthenes
  for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) {

    // if i is prime, then mark multiples of i as nonprime
    // suffices to consider mutiples i, i+1, ..., N/i
    if (isPrime.get(i)) {
      for (int j = i; i * j <= n; j++) {
          isPrime.clear(i * j);
      }
    }

  }

  //System.out.println("Found " + isPrime.cardinality() + " primes");
  return isPrime;
}
```

Comment: It appears you caught me not documenting my code super well! 
1. 'sum' starts at 3 because I do not test whether or not 1 and 2 are prime-generating using the algorithm; however, they both are prime generating, and 1+2 = 3.
2. I added 'done' as a way to give me the correct sum for smaller values of 'n' . That was my first indication that something was going wrong, because it gives an answer that's about 5 too big without 'done'
3. I think you're right about not putting break in the correct spot. I'll have to reconsider that.
4. According to someone else's work, the sum should be 1739023853137

Comment: That all sounds reasonable. I think if you make the two changes I suggest (remove one `break` and add another) we will get a more reasonable figure. Mine's still running (low end laptop) ... at about 17,000,000 atm. I'll update my post as soon as it has finished. Once the run completes and I get a figure I will remove `done` and re-run. I suspect that will make no difference. I hope the figure I get is your `1739023853137`. Are you confident this is the correct figure?

Comment: Paul, it will run rather long, I'm afraid. A better algorithm is needed. But you're right about the breaks and the done.

Comment: It is indeed the right figure. Based on your comments, I was able to arrive at the right answer and Project Euler accepted it!
I also optimized it so that it runs much faster.
Instead of starting 'sum' at '3', I changed 'sum' to start at '1', and  instead of 'for(int j = 2; j < i/2; j++)', I realized that you can use 'for(int j = 2; j < Math.sqrt(i+3); j++)'
It ran in a matter of seconds instead of minutes.
Also, thanks a bunch for the BitSet tip - we didn't learn about those in Intro to Data Structures!

Comment: Oh, and yes, your number of primes less than 10^8 is correct.

Comment: That finished much quicker and I get the same answer. :D Thanks for the "Answered".