# Java Program to find sum of all prime numbers below 2,000,000 (Project Euler)

Tags: java

I am attempting to solve Project Euler's 10<sup>th</sup> question, but for some reason I can't get it right. I'm really new at programming and Java, so I can't understand why it isn't working. The point of the question is to find the sum of all the primes below 2,000,000.

```
/*  The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.

    Find the sum of all the primes below two million.
*/  

public static void main(String[] args){

    long n = 1;
    long sum = 0;
    long limit;

    System.out.println("Enter the limit of n: ");
    limit = TextIO.getlnLong(); //TextIO is another input method
    while (limit <= 0){
        System.out.println("Enter the limit of n (must be positive): ");
        limit = TextIO.getlnLong();

    }       

    while (n < limit){ 
        n++;
        if (n % 2 != 0 && n % 3 != 0 && n % 5 != 0 && n % 7 != 0 && n != 1 || n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 5 || n == 7){ //this is my prime checking method, might be flawed

            sum = sum + n;  
            System.out.println(+sum);
        } //end if

    }//end while

    System.out.println("The sum of the primes below 2,000,000 is: " +sum);

} //end of main
```

Comment: Your prime checking method is certainly flawed.

Comment: I also recommend factoring the prime checking out into a separate method.

Comment: Here's a proven [Sieve](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8780876/823393) you can use.

Comment: 121 = 11*11.  That's not prime....perfect square, yes.

Comment: Whenever you post on SO, please state your question very clearly. Although people can compile and run the code and see the problem you post, it is better to clearly indicate if your program is not compiling or you are getting some incorrect answer. Although in your case, the flawed logic as indicated by many was easily caught.

Answer (score 4):

For an *efficient* prime checking method, read up on the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: For numbers up to 2 million he certainly doesn't need something overly efficient. I expect the naive implementation to take a couple of seconds.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Maybe, but bruteforcing stuff generally isn't in the spirit of projecteuler, and he'll definitely need something efficient for later prime-related problems.

Comment: The Sieve would require some kind of set, list, or vector to handle the increasing set of primes found. Nested for loops and dynamically sized data structures big be too much for zsherman at the moment

Comment: @JustinDanielson The sieve itself indicates whether each number is a prime, no need to store the numbers outside the sieve.

Comment: I actually solved this one with the Sieve of Eratosthenes too. It's INCREDIBLY useful to have for later problems. (It runs in just 0.05 seconds).

Answer (score 2):

Your prime method is broken. A number is prime if it does not have any divisors between 2 and the square root of the number. 13*13 would pass your prime check function.

```
for i to sqrt(n):
   if(n % i == 0):
       OH NO NOT PRIME DO SOMETHING HERE?
if something is prime
   add some stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 solutions that are better than the trivial solution:

**1) Iterating through the odd numbers** ( the only even prime number is already in the sum ) and check if they are prime:

```
private static boolean isOddPrime(int x) {
    for ( int i = 3 ; i*i <= x ; i+=2 ){ 
        if ( x % i == 0 ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static void sumOfPrimes1(int n) {       
    long sum = 2;
    for ( int i = 3 ; i < n ; i+=2 ) {
        if ( isOddPrime(i) ) {
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum); 
}
```

**2)** Using the **Sieve of Eratosthenes**

```
private static void sumOfPrimes2(int n) {
    boolean notPrimes[] = new boolean[n];   // default = false
    for ( int i = 2 ; i*i < n ; i++ ) {
        if ( !notPrimes[i] ) {
            for ( int j = i*i ; j < n ; j+=i ){
                notPrimes[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    long sum = 2 ;
    for ( int i = 3 ; i < n ; i+=2 ) {
        if ( !notPrimes[i] ) {
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

I used "notPrimes" (composites) instead of "primes" as array just to use in my advantage the fact that the default boolean value in Java is `false`.

**Performance**:

```
n           |    2000000        8000000       16000000
------------+-------------------------------------------
Solution 1  |    1309 ms        8574 ms       22757 ms
Solution 2  |    119 ms         696 ms        1624 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.counton.org/explorer/primes/checking-if-a-number-is-prime/

One short cut to check a number N is prime is we don’t have to try each number in turn from 2 to N (2, 3, 4, 5, 6 …..N-1) to see any of them divide exactly N.

exp : Since 3 is a factor of 18 and 18/3=6, then 18=3x6. We need only test the smaller number, 3, to see if it is a factor of 18 and not 6. Similarly, 5 is a factor 20 and 20=5x4 so we need only test the smaller number 4 as a factor. But what if we don't know the factors of a number? So, testing a number to see if it is prime means we need only test the "smaller" factors. But where do smaller factors stop and larger factors start? The principle here is:
Suppose one number is a factor of N and that it is smaller than the square-root of the number N. Then the second factor must be larger than the square-root.
We can see this with the examples above: For 18, we need only test numbers up to the square-root of 18 which is 4.243, ie up to 4! This is much quicker than testing all the numbers up to 17!!
For 25, we need to test numbers up to and including the square-root of 25, which is 5.
And for 37, we need only go up to 6 (since 6x6=36 so the square-root of 37 will be only a little bit larger).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < 2000000; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}

// check if a number is prime
private static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(number);
    boolean isPrime = true;

   // test up to square root of the number
   for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isPrime;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
  long n = 1;
  long sum = 0;
  long limit=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

  while (n < limit)
  {
    n++;
    if(n % 2 != 0 && n % 3 != 0 && n % 5 != 0 && n % 7 != 0 && n != 1 || n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 5 || n == 7)
    {
      sum = sum + n;
    }
  }


    System.out.println("The sum of the prime numbers = " +sum);
 }
```

Comment: Could you add some text that describes how this answers the question?

Comment: Ditto. Explanations are always appreciated. Otherwise you leave everyone with the task of playing spot-the-difference

Comment: here n is starting number and limit is range which can be 2000000. while  loop is used to check numbers upto the limit. now inside the loop each number will be checked for prime or not with the help of given if condition. if its a prime num, it will be added to sum. finally all prime numbers will be added to sum and sum is printed.

Comment: @Sheena, yes i agree its ditto!! but i have made some changes which i thought were easy to understand others.

Comment: how will it actually calculate the prime below 2 million, not helpul and not working in any manner, what so ever